# Mercurial queues: having patches shared by multiple queues?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have a local repo with two patch queues, `patches` and `myproject`. One is for bug fixes in the release branch, and one is for work on a separate project.

- patches:   local-config debug bugfix1 bugfix2
- myproject: local-config myproject1 myproject2

I would like to have a single copy of the `local-config` patch which is shared by both queues. One possible solution is to symlink patches-myproject/local-config to ../patches/local-config.

Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can easily or safely share a patch between queues.  You could consider having one queue and using `guards` to say which patches should be applied at any given time.